# Can't override X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" with X-Frame-Options "" in the same nginx conf file

Tags: nginx, iframe, x-frame-options

I have an nginx conf file containing some generic lines that I deploy on several websites. Among those lines I have this:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
```

For certain websites I want to deploy some custom lines. For example there are a few websites for which I want to deploy the following because I want to allow them to be loaded in some iframes:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "";
```

So, those websites conf files end-up containing something like this:

```
# some generic settings
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
...

# some custom settings
add_header X-Frame-Options "";
...
```

The problem is that the second `add_header X-Frame-Options` doesn't override the first.
I also tried to switch the settings and I put the custom ones first and then the generic ones. So the conf file looked like this:

```
# some custom settings
add_header X-Frame-Options "";
...
    
# some generic settings
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
...
```

But again, the setting for `X-Frame-Options` was `"SAMEORIGIN"` and not `""`.

My question is: is there any possibility to override that X-Frame-Options add_header setting once it is set?

I'm running nginx 1.20 on a Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override it by setting Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors directive. For all but legacy browsers, this will override X-Frame-Options. Try

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *;
```

You might not need 'self' (equals to XFO SAMEORIGIN), you can test without it.

Comment: Simple and effective! Thank you. I ended-up using this line in order to allow embedding from only one domain and its subdomains.
`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *.allowed-domain.com;`